# MySQL - unique restraint on combination of columns: avoiding error?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, unique

I have a unique restraint on a combination of columns, rather than on a single one. Naturally, MySQL errors if I then try to insert data that violates this restraint.

This is via PHP > CodeIgniter, by the way.

**My question is:** on inesrt, what is the suggested way of handling this? Should I...

- be suppressing the error? (#flameme)
- be running a query first to ensure it doesn't happen?
- allow the error because it doesn't cause any visible issue to the user?
- be using `replace into` rather than `insert into`? (I believe CodeIgniter's Active Record class doesn't provide access to `replace into`, though?)

**Context:**

I have a tags table, which stores tags that users create to categorise their content:

- id (PK, int, AI, unsigned)
- tag (varchar 25)
- user_id (FK, int, unsigned)

A given user is not able create a tag he has previously created, hence the unique restraint is on the combination of the id and user_id columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$insert_query = $this->db->insert_string('my_table', $data);
$insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO','INSERT IGNORE INTO',$insert_query);
$this->db->query($insert_query);
```

I think this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Add key with type `UNIQUE` to `tag`+`user_id` in Your MySQL table. After that [set handler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to `ON DUPLICATE KEY` at Your query. You needn't to suppressing errors while You can avoid them ;)

Comment: Thanks for this - `insert ignore` proved too attractive to, er, ignore.

Comment: @Utkanos no, You shouldn't use it in this way. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: Yeah I actually saw that question. I agree with its points; however, in my case, ignoring the warning won't cause any issue.